# Statistical significance of a nls model in R

Tags: r, nls, non-linear-regression, significance

I have some multiple linear models without intercept like below:

```
Y = a*X1 + b*X2 + c*X3
```

However this model is a linear model, but since it does not have an intercept we have to write it as a non-linear model in R:

```
model1= nls(Y ~ a*X1+b*X2, data = trainDat, start = list(a = 1, b=1))
```

The problem is that the `summary(model1)` does not give us the statistics of the model like F-statistics because it is not `lm`.
How can we report the significance of these models in R?

Comment: You can fit a linear, no-intercept model with `lm(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 - 1)`.

Comment: An f-test is just one of many things `summary.lm` does. You can do an f-test on a nls object with `var.test(...)`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did not get your meaning regards to your point about F-test on a nls model. The function could be var(model1) in my case? It does not work!

Comment: I know this is not the place to talk about statistics but what's the point to do not fit a linear model just because "it does not have an intercept"? that's meaningless.